# jump if greater executing unexpectedly

Tags: x86, x86-64

I am writing a simple part of a project which checks if a given temperature input value is out of range, in this case greater than 28800. I will then have it jump to handle the error state if the input is greater than 28800. However, it appears that my `jg` is executing when I think it should not, **when input is equal to 0**. Does it appear that my bug is located in this snippet of code or else where?

`%r8` holds input.

```
movq    $28800, %r11
cmp     %r8, %r11
jg      .IF_SET_TEMPS_FROM_PORTS_ERROR
```

Comment: AT&T syntax backwards operands strikes again.  `28800 > 0` so the jg is taken.  `cmp $28800, %r8` ; `jg` should work.

Comment: I had though I had tried that, turns out I did just I did not compile my full program, thanks